# Rails 4 Data Toggle link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

How can I use the link_to method in Rails 4 to provide the same effect as

```
  <a href="(mysite.example.com)" class="tooltips" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Facebook">
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
<%= link_to 'my site', 'mysite.example.com', { :class => 'tooltips', 'data-toggle' => 'tooltip', 'data-placement' => 'top', :title => '', 'data-original-title' => 'Facebook' } %>
```

Or

```
<%= link_to 'my site', root_path, class: 'tooltips', title: '', data: { toggle: 'tooltip', placement: 'top', original_title: 'Facebook' } %>
```

Or

```
<%= link_to 'my site', { controller: 'home', action: 'index' }, { class: 'tooltips', title: '', data: { toggle: 'tooltip', placement: 'top', original_title: 'Facebook' } } %>
```

Comment: Thanks I was having a hard time getting the right syntax

Comment: It's slightly confusing because there are multiple definitions of `link_to` and most of them take two hashes as arguments, which means that just listing options won't work in most cases. Check out Signatures section on http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to

Comment: Thanks I was definitely struggling with understanding this, will do

Comment: interesting, when using this in nav-pills, clicking on the links does not do anything when adding in this data-toggle option, it seems to completely disable them for me

Answer (score 0):

A simple working example to copy and edit:

```
<%= link_to "My hidden stuff", "#collapseArea", { class: "btn btn-light", 'data-toggle': "collapse" } %><br><br>

<div class="collapse" id="collapseArea">
  <p>Hidden</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>goes</p>
  <p>here</p>
</div>
```