# Rails 4: add multiple data-toggle inside link_to helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, bootstrap-modal, link-to

In my Rails 4 app, inside my views, I use a lot of `link_to` helpers.

When I need to add a Bootstrap `tooltip` to a link, I do:

```
<%= link_to "Link text", model_path(@model), "data-toggle" => "tooltip", "data-placement" => "bottom", "title" => "Model View" %>
```

And, when I need to add a Bootstrap `modal` to a link, I do:

```
<%= link_to  "Link text", model_path(@model), :remote => true, 'data-toggle' =>  "modal", 'data-target' => '#modal-window' %>
```

Now, in one particular place in my app, I need to add **BOTH** a `tooltip` **AND** a `modal` on the same link.

I have found two Stack Overflow questions, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16402390/bootstrap-control-with-multiple-data-toggle) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29435959/rails-4-data-toggle-link-to), which explain how to add several `data-toggle` attributes in Rails, but none of them offers a solution to implement this **INSIDE** a `link_to` helper.

Is that actually possible?

Comment: I don't think you can, but could you just wrap your link in a `<div>` or a `<span>` and put the tool tip on that?

Comment: Sure, I am going to try this and let you know.

Comment: Worked like a charm, perfect. Feel free to add your comment as an answer, I will be more than happy to approve it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Great, glad it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can, but could you just wrap your link in a `<div>` or a `<span>` and put the tool tip on that.